# How is the time complexity O(n) and not O(n^2)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I am solving a question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-product-less-than-k/description/):

> Given a vector `nums` of positive integers, count and print the number of (contiguous) subarrays where the product of all the elements in the subarray is less than k.

The code (which I wrote with substantial online help) is as follows:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numSubarrayProductLessThanK(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        if(nums.empty() || k<=1) return 0;

        int counter=0, left=0, currProd=1;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) {
            currProd*=nums[i];
            while(left<nums.size() && currProd>=k)
                currProd/=nums[left++];
            counter+=i-left+1;
        }

        return counter;
    }
};
```

While I understand what is going on, I fail to understand how the time complexity is said to be `O(n)` and not `O(n^2)`.  IMHO, both `i` and `left` are incremented, resulting in visiting each element of `nums` twice in the worst case - once by the inductive variable `i` and then by `left`.

How, then, is the time complexity `O(n)`?

Comment: If you have a loop in a loop you generally run into *O(n^2)* situations.

Comment: @tadman, and yet, the time complexity is said to be _O(n)_.

Comment: That might be true in theory, but I don't think your code meets that criteria. You may need another approach. For  *O(n)* you'll need to do a one pass approach with a single loop.

Comment: Looks more like O(2n) which infact is O(n).

Comment: @tadman, _approach_ as in?  To analyze the time complexity or to solve the question (FYI: this solution was accepted, meaning that all the test cases passed successfully within the time limit).

Comment: @tkausl It depends on how often `left` moves, as worst-case it's never moving and it has to scan the whole thing N*N times.

Comment: I think to be truly *O(n)* you need to get rid of the inner `while` so it's a simple linear scan. You may need to employ a few clever tricks to get that to go away.

Comment: "It depends on how often left moves, as worst-case it's never moving and it has to scan the whole thing N*N times." the inner loop always increments it though, and the outer one never resets it, so the inner loop will never execute more than n times.

Comment: I think if it qualifies as O(n), it's because the `left` is never reset to zero inside a loop, and thus the "inner loop" will never iterate more than `mums.size()` times regardless of how many times the outer loop iterates.

Comment: @tkausl Yeah, I'm seeing that now. Personally I'd prefer that `left` was a pointer or an iterator and not an index, since then you can get rid of that confusing array reference notation.

Comment: @tadman, I believe in writing clear and readable code.  Although I have accepted an answer, I would appreciate it if you could explain what you mean when you say, _"Personally I'd prefer that left was a pointer or an iterator and not an index, since then you can get rid of that confusing array reference notation."_  Thank you.

Comment: If you had `left` set as an iterator over that vector (e.g. `auto left = nums.begin()`) then you can use `*left` to get the value, and `++left` to move it along. There's no need to do `nums[left++]`, especially when it has a "sneaky" post-increment in it. This is just a minor quibble when random access is cheap, but an iterator or pointer sometimes conveys the intent better such as more directly "walking through" something rather than keeping an index that just happens to be an offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the code might look deceptively `O(N^2)`-like, the critical thing to note is that:

> Inside the for-loop, `left` is never reset to 0, and is always incremented in the while-loop.

This means that the `while` loop can only execute a maximum of `N` times during the **entire** execution of the code. Therefore the code only runs through the array twice, hence `O(N)`.

Comment: Yes, I get that.  But my doubt is this: `i` visits all the elements once; `left` (albeit that it is not reset) visits all the elements (for a given value of `i`).  So, how is it still `O(n)`?

Comment: `left` visits every element only once over the entire run, not during each for-loop execution.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the body of the inner loop is executed, `left` is incremented by 1. `left` is initially 0 and never grows beyond `nums.size()`. Therefore the body of the inner loop is executed at most `nums.size()` times.

The body of the outer loop is executed exactly `nums.size()` times.

Therefore the execution time of the function is at most `T0 + nums.size() * T1 + nums.size() * T2` where T0 is the time it takes to execute the code outside the outer loop, T1 is the time it takes to execute one iteration of the outer loop not including the inner loop, and T2 is the time it takes to execute one iteration of the inner loop. This upper bound is of the form `A + nums.size() * B` where A and B are some constants. Therefore the execution time of the function is `O(nums.size())`.

When you have two nested loops, the complexity of the whole program is *at most* `M*N` where `M` is the number of iterations of the outer loop and `N` is the *maximum* number of iterations of the inner loop. Thus the complexity of the program satisfies `O(M*N)`. Sometimes it's possible to find a lower bound because the number of iterations of the inner loop varies. Here, there is an invariant that guarantees that the inner loop executes at most a certain number of times *total*, which gives a better bound than `O(nums.size() * nums.size())`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It was helpful.